# Finding the position of a single array in a list of arrays that contains wildcard variables

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Consider two lists:

```
superList = {{wc,wc,1,wc,wc}, {wc, wc,2, wc, wc}, {wc, wc, 3, wc, wc}, {wc, wc, 4, wc, wc}};
littleList = {a,b,3,c,25};
```

In `superList`, the `wc` variable stands for "wild card" and should be considered a "match" to any other variable it is compared with (for example `wc == 1` and `wc == q` should return `TRUE`).

Is there a nice way to find the position of `littleList` in `superList`, perhaps with `Position`?

As an update, let me be a bit more clear here in what I'm looking to learn - I'd like to understand how to create very general wildcard variables that will return `TRUE` for queries (with either general variables or a set of pre-specified variables) of the form `wc == a && wc == b`.  There must be a general way to do this in Mathematica, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a *Mathematica* construct that is like your wildcard: the pattern `_`.  (See [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html).)
I would therefore start with that replacement:

```
sL2 = superList /. wc -> _
```

> ```
> {{_, _, 1, _, _}, {_, _, 2, _, _}, {_, _, 3, _, _}, {_, _, 4, _, _}}
> ```

Then use [`MatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatchQ.html), since your matching is the reverse of the normal operation:

```
MatchQ[littleList, #] & /@ sL2
Position[%, True]
```

> ```
> {False, False, True, False}
>
> {{3}}
> ```

In one line:

```
Position[sL2, x_ /; MatchQ[littleList, x], {1}]
```

> ```
> {{3}}
> ```

Comment: LOL this is better than mine :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1

```
Position[Inner[If[#1 === wc, True, #1 == #2] &, #, littleList, And] & /@ superList, True]
```

Output is the following:

```
 {{3}}
```

#### Method 2

```
Position[Inner[Equal, #, littleList, And] & /@ superList /. Equal[wc, x_] :> True, True]
```

Output is the following:

```
{{3}}
```

#### Function version

> how might I use that in the context of a function where I already have '#' representing littleList as an input?

You could do this:

```
P[a_] := Position[Inner[Equal, #, a, And] & /@ superList /. Equal[wc, x_] :> True, True];
P[littleList]
```

which produces

```
{{3}}
```

#### Unprotecting system functions

You can unprotect a system attribute like this:

```
Unprotect[Equal]
Equal[wc, x_] := True
```

Now when you execute the following,

```
wc == 3
```

you get

```
True
```

Comment: That works!  However, shouldn't there be a way to use wildcards more generally?  Can I designate that some variable 'wc' will return TRUE everywhere for comparisons wc == a and wc == b (for example)?

Comment: @Asterisked: See edit. Is this what you are looking for? Unfortunately, executing `Equal[wc, x_] := True` to globally designate `wc` to be a wildcard gives an error, since `Equal` is protected. There might be a way around this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Yes, that's a lot closer to what I'm looking for. :) However, how might I use that in the context of a function where I already have '#' representing littleList as an input?

Comment: @Asterisked: See edit.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is posed

```
Position[superList, littleList /. {__, a_Integer, __} :> {_, _, a, _, _}]
```

> {{3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
sa = SparseArray[superList, Automatic, wc];
check = littleList[[#2]] === sa[[##]] & @@@ sa["NonzeroPositions"]
(* {False,False,True,False} *)

Position[check, True]
(* {{3}} *)
```

Comment: +1 for use of the old bludgeon.  Something similar using associations:  `KeyTake[Join @@ KeyDrop[wc]@*PositionIndex /@ superList, 3] // Values`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `old bludgeon` indeed:)